# serilization daughter classes

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to serialize a class that has daughter classes but it does not allow me when I go to complete the json it gives me an error

This is the json file as it should look:

```
{
  "User": "jhuan.caasillas",
  "Passwd": "#########",
  "IdAplicativo": 2001,
  "Firma": "asdlkhg=saldkja=="
}




"Mensaje": {
        "CodigoMensaje": 320,
        "DescMensaje": "Exito"
    },
    "Roles": [
        {
            "Descripcion": "juan casillas"
        },
        {
            "Descripcion": "al21"
        },
        {
            "Descripcion": "comandos"
        },
        {
            "Descripcion": "identificado"
        }
    ]
}
```

I have this class with these methods created
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uz7dI.png)

when I go to fill these methods with the json it doesn't allow me and I get the error

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'serialize.Roles' to 'serialize.Roles[]' serialize
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/btFMA.png)

I would like to know how I can fill the json array that I showed previously

Comment: your `Roles` property is an array of type `Roles`, you are trying to initialize it as if it were just one.

Comment: Please re-read the [mre] guidance, in particular part about "do not post images of code" and [edit] the post accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If Roles is array it must be initialized as array

```
DominioRes res1 = new DominioRes
{
    Roles = new Roles[]
    {
        new Roles
        {
            Description="juan casillas"
        },
        new Roles
        {
            Description="al21"
        },
        new Roles
        {
            Description="comandos"
        },
        new Roles
        {
            Description="identificado"
        }
    }
};
```